# Different results with torchvision transforms

Tags: python-imaging-library, transform, torchvision

Correct me if I am wrong.
The 'classic' way to pass images through torchvision `transforms` is to
use `Compose` as in its doc page. This, however, requires to pass `Image` input.
An alternative is to use `ConvertImageDtype` with `torch.nn.Sequential`. This 'bypasses'
the need for `Image`, and in my case it is much faster because I work with numpy arrays.

My problem is that results are not identical.
Below is an example with custom `Normalize`.
I would like to use `torch.nn.Sequential` (`tr`) because it is faster for my needs,
but the error compared to `Compose` (`tr2`) is very large (~810).

```
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as T
import numpy as np
import torch

o = np.random.rand(64, 64, 3) * 255
o = np.array(o, dtype=np.uint8)
i = Image.fromarray(o)

tr = torch.nn.Sequential(
    T.Resize(224, interpolation=T.InterpolationMode.BICUBIC),
    T.CenterCrop(224),
    T.ConvertImageDtype(torch.float),
    T.Normalize([0.48145466, 0.4578275, 0.40821073], [0.26862954, 0.26130258, 0.27577711]),
)

tr2 = T.Compose([
    T.Resize(224, interpolation=T.InterpolationMode.BICUBIC),
    T.CenterCrop(224),
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize((0.48145466, 0.4578275, 0.40821073), (0.26862954, 0.26130258, 0.27577711)),
])

out = tr(torch.from_numpy(o).permute(2,0,1).contiguous())

out2 = tr2(i)

print(((out - out2) ** 2).sum())
```

The interpolation method seems to matter A LOT, and if I use the default `BILINEAR` the error is ~7, but I need to use `BICUBIC`.

The problem seems to lie in `ConvertImageDtype` vs `ToTensor`, because if I replace
`ToTensor` with `ConvertImageDtype` results are identical (cannot do the other way around
because `ToTensor` is not a subclass of `Module` and I cannot use it with `nn.Sequential`).

However, the following gives identical results

```
tr = torch.nn.Sequential(
    T.ConvertImageDtype(torch.float),
)

tr2 = T.Compose([
    T.ToTensor(),
])

out = tr(torch.from_numpy(o).permute(2,0,1).contiguous())

out2 = tr2(i)

print(((out - out2) ** 2).sum())
```

This means that the interpolation changes something in the results, which matters only
when I use `ToTensor` vs `ConvertImageDtype`.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize):

> The output image might be different depending on its type: when downsampling, the interpolation of PIL images and tensors is slightly different, because PIL applies antialiasing. This may lead to significant differences in the performance of a network. Therefore, it is preferable to train and serve a model with the same input types. See also below the `antialias` parameter, which can help making the output of PIL images and tensors closer.

Passing `antialias=True` produces almost identical results.
This is interesting because the doc says that

> it can be set to True for `InterpolationMode.BILINEAR` only mode.

Yet, I am using `BICUBIC` and still works.